# UnicodeDecodeError on Python 3.5 when doing SQL query

Tags: python, unicode, pyodbc

I was using Python 3.5 + pyodbc (on windows 10) to do apply some SQL queries on a server, and everything was doing fine like this:

```
In [1]: import pyodbc
   ...:
In [2]: server = 'tcp:192.168.100.76'
   ...: database = 'database'
   ...: username = 'username'
   ...: password = 'password'
   ...:
In [3]: cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+use
   ...: rname+';PWD='+ password)
   ...: cursor = cnxn.cursor()

In [29]: sqlQuery = "SELECT TOP 50 * " + \
    ...: "FROM dbo.DS10_CIBBASE " + \
    ...: "LEFT JOIN dbo.DS10_CIBCITY AS O_CITY ON dbo.DS10_CIBBASE.O_CITY=O_CITY.CITYCODE " + \
    ...: "LEFT JOIN dbo.DS10_CIBCITY AS B_CITY ON dbo.DS10_CIBBASE.B_CITY=B_CITY.CITYCODE " + \
    ...: "LEFT JOIN dbo.DS10_CIBMETH AS METHOD1 ON dbo.DS10_CIBBASE.METHOD1=METHOD1.METHCODE " + \
    ...: "LEFT JOIN dbo.DS10_CIBMETH AS METHOD2 ON dbo.DS10_CIBBASE.METHOD2=METHOD2.METHCODE " + \
    ...: "LEFT JOIN dbo.DS10_CIBMETH AS METHOD3 ON dbo.DS10_CIBBASE.METHOD3=METHOD3.METHCODE " + \
    ...: "LEFT JOIN dbo.DS10_CIBPERS ON dbo.DS10_CIBBASE.BASENO=dbo.DS10_CIBPERS.BASENO " + \
    ...: "LEFT JOIN dbo.DS10_CIBFEAT ON dbo.DS10_CIBPERS.FEATURE=dbo.DS10_CIBFEAT.FEATCODE " + \
    ...: "LEFT JOIN dbo.DS10_CIBOCCU ON dbo.DS10_CIBPERS.OCCUPATION= dbo.DS10_CIBOCCU.OCCUCODE " + \
    ...: "LEFT JOIN dbo.DS10_CIBEDUC ON dbo.DS10_CIBPERS.EDU=dbo.DS10_CIBEDUC.EDUCCODE " + \
    ...: "LEFT JOIN dbo.DS10_CIBCITY AS L_CITY ON dbo.DS10_CIBPERS.CITY=L_CITY.CITYCODE ;"

In [30]: cursor.execute(sqlQuery)
Out[30]: <pyodbc.Cursor at 0x262625e5750>
```

So far so good, and then I changed the query a little bit:

```
In [31]: sqlQuery0 = "SELECT TOP 50 * " + \
    ...: "FROM dbo.LAB1_EXP3_CARNO1 ; "

In [32]: cursor.execute(sqlQuery0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-769696011e11> in <module>()
----> 1 cursor.execute(sqlQuery0)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa8 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

I could not figure why the previous query was fine, while the later encountered the *UnicodeDecodeError*, since all the queries were written with ASCII characters..  So what did I do wrong, and how could I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting this because your data is not UTF-8 encoded (`\U00A8` is "spacing diaeresis", and `\xA8` is the same in Latin-1, but `\xA8` is `š` in Latin-15.
The error is not because the query has non-ascii characters (obviously, it doesn't), but because the result is returning a string of 8-bit characters that aren't UTF-8 encoded.

For SQL server, you can use `cast` or `convert` to change the `varchar` column causing the error into an `nvarchar` (UTF-16 Unicode) value.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be this problem. I ran the script on linux machine, and this UnicodeDecodeError did not occur. So one more thing, when using `CAST`, should I specify the columns that cause this error? or can I simply use something like `SELECT CAST(TOP 50 * AS nvarchar)` (btw, this did not work..)?

Comment: No, you'll have to cast each column individually (but you only need to do the varchar columns, and only those that might have non-ascii characters).  Alternatively, if you know what encoding is being used, you can do the conversion in Python (using `.encode`)