# Writing to .txt adding b and '' to my headers

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyodbc

I recently upgrading from python 2 to python 3. I have a code that queries a database via `pyodbc`.

Now when I output the results of these queries my files add `b` before each header, and quotes `''` around each header. i.e. `b'Header_Name'`, `b'Header_Name2'`

Does anyone know why this is? I thought it may be the `open` function `w+`, I have tried this with `w` here with the same error.

```
output_file = open(working_dir + "E"+str(s)+".txt", "w+")
cursor.execute(sql_string)

headers = []
col_count = 0
for col in cursor.description:
    print(str(col[0]) + '|',)
    headers.append(str(col[0]).encode("utf-8"))
    col_count = col_count + 1

output_file.write(','.join([str(v) for v in headers]) + "\n")

i = 0

for row in cursor:
    a=0
    values = []
    while a < col_count:
        values.append(str(row[a]))
        a=a+1

    output_file.write(','.join(values) + "\n")
    i = i + 1

output_file.close()
```

Comment: its not originally my code actually, so i am not to familiar with `encode` or why they did it.

Comment: Also, if you want to know a bit more about encoding / decoding and why you're getting this problem, check out [this link](https://realpython.com/python-encodings-guide/#encoding-and-decoding-in-python-3)! :)

Comment: If your code is *explicitly* encoding results as UTF-8 then that might go a long way to explain some of the confusion regarding [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57402005/2144390).